# read a random line from text file converting it from utf-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, type-conversion

I have a text file that has Chinese characters in it.

I want to read a random line from that text file and display it, here is my code:

```
from random import randint
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('Chinese.txt'))
num_lines = num_lines - 1

choice = raw_input('How many times do you want to play?')
choice1 = int(choice)
while choice1 > 0:
    random_number = (randint(0,num_lines))

    with open('Chinese.txt') as inputFile:

        bytes = inputFile.readlines()
        unicodeText = bytes.decode('utf-8')
    print unicodeText[int(random_number)]
    choice1 = choice1 - 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

readlines produces a list of lines that you can use `random.choice` to pick for you randomly.

```
from random import randint, choice
...
        bytes = inputFile.readlines()
        random_line = choice(bytes)
    print random_line.decode("utf-8")
```

Also, in Python 3 `bytes` is a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#built-in-functions), I suggest renaming that variable to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually decode each line. Instead, use the `io` module to open the file in text mode with the appropriate encoding specified. All strings read from the file will now be Unicodes:

```
with open('Chinese.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inputFile:
    lines = inputFile.readlines()
    random_line = choice(lines)

# type(random_line)
# Unicode
print random_line
```